# Apple Rules about UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am new in app development. Question is about Apple rules and application rejection.

Can I use two `UINavigationBar` (different functionality), one below one? Does Apple's rules accept that?

Comment: Only Apple can say what they will or won't accept, so this really calls for a lot of speculation. Generally, if it's a good design, easy to use, and doesn't abuse the user interface, you're probably on solid ground. It's hard to see how two navigation bars would fit that description, though.

Answer (score 2):

I can definitely tell you it's against the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52), since

> A navigation bar appears at the upper edge of an application screen, just below the status bar.

(Since one of your navigation bars wouldn't be at the upper edge of the screen).

Will your app actually get rejected? There's only one way to find out, but I would suggest not committing such a heinous crime against the principles of aesthetics and design.

Comment: He's talking about navigation bars, not tab bars, but the heinous crime line still fits.

Answer (score 2):

This is [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). There are no words about rejecting for several UINavigationBar. But there is a below phrase.

> If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be
>   rejected

Comment: ok,if design and user interaction is good then app may not be rejected right..